# variable user in jwt authentication tutorial

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

I'm new to angular, and following [this](http://amcdnl.com/2017/08/06/angular-jwt-auth/) tutorial but I'm wondering how he defines the variable user in the `"authenticationService"` file.Can I assume this a any and pass it any username/password data structure? Any comment will be highly appreciated.

Comment: the author doesn't show the implementation of the 'login' REST call, therefore you can assume that it is taking the string representation of a 'user' object.  For the purposes of the tutorial, it doesn't matter, and the actual call will be dependent on the 'login' service you use.

Comment: @MatthewHegarty could you suggest an implementation for the login form?